# CSS runs title instead of HTML

Tags: css, title

I've looked, this has never been answered.

I have many HTML pages that used a template, the template is stuck and since I'm using only HTML, CSS & slightly JavaScript I need a solution that changes where people look for the title.

I want CSS to have a title, I only have 1 CSS page and about 15 / 20 HTML pages with the  tag undefined. Is there a way to have CSS contain the title?

Thank you if you can,

Comment: Changes where people look for the title?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "css to have a title" could you explain that in greater detail? Also, showing the relevant markup and CSS will help others get you an answer.

Comment: I don't think CSS is supposed to have a title. On a related note, `<title>` can't be styled using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is a language used only for styling webpages. It is not used to store data so you will not be able to store the title in the CSS.

One bad approach could be that just write the title on the CSS file on the first line then use Javascript and then read the file's first line and set that as the title using Javascript.

One good approach could be that set the title using javascript. Make a simple javascript file and add `document.title='your_title';` in that and include that in every HTML page. That will create a title for your webpage but ofcourse that will be equal to adding a `<title>` tag on every HTML page, the difference would be only of not writing `<title>` but writing some script.

Or one another approach could be that make some C# or any other language in which you are at your best program that will insert a title attribute in your HTML file :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean the `title` element within `head`, one option, if you can, would be to use JavaScript.

```
// set current title to foo
document.title = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add text to a particular element with CSS you can use the pseudo-selector "before":

```
#title:before {
  content: "Your title";
}
```

Comment: this will not work for the TITLE tag in the had of a document.